# How to make volume levels universal

Tags: sound, 15.04, headphones, volume-control, speakers

I have noticed that my volume level is device-specific. For instance, I have 100% volume before plugging-in my headphones. After plugging my headphones in, if I change the volume down to 40%, the volume goes back up to 100% when I unplug my headphones. Additionally, when I plug them back in, the volume returns back to 40%. So it seems that the volume level is device specific.

This may be useful for some, but I really don't want it. I want it so that the volume is universal, so that it doesn't change to the last volume setting it was on when I last had that particular device plugged in.

This is a screenshot of my system settings when I don't have my headphones plugged in:

[image: Speakers only]

And immediately as I plug my headphones in the settings change to this:

[image: Headphones]

So my question is rather clear, how do I make the volume universal for all devices?

I am running Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: By the way, I updated the version information as I have upgraded and still have the problem.

Comment: what's the output of `cat /etc/pulse/daemon.conf | grep flat`? this is not happening on my machine when I plug headphones in.

Comment: Which output plugged the cable?

Comment: @JoKeR: This is the output: `flat-volumes = no`

Comment: @A.B.: What do you mean?

Comment: seems ok, I cannot reproduce your problem as it doesn't affect my pc though I can give you hints where to look /usr/share/pulseadio/alsa-mixer/paths you'll find .conf files in there and for headphones/jack too, once I edited `pcm element` I had kinda similar issue before that after reboot it didn't want to store my `pcm` setting for sound so I changed pcm element `volume=merge` to `volume=ignore` and it worked for all outputs ;)

Comment: how about alsamixer? have you tried to set it?

Comment: @bagustris: No, I have not, how does that work then?

Comment: just type "alsamixer' in command line,  set the level for headphone and speaker in the same level,  use right/left arrow to move from one to other and up/low to increase/decrease volume.

Comment: @bagustris: So if I then were to increase or decrease the volume using, say, the keyboard shortcut for the volume control, would it change both levels, or would I have to go back in and manually alter them, if so, then this does not really make the volume level universal, and doesn't achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make volume levels universal for all devices you will have to edit a `/etc/pulse/default.pa` file. So, to do it in gedit with root permissions run:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

This is an excerpt of the file:

```
### Automatically restore the volume of streams and devices
load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore
```

Comment the 2nd line so it is not in use any more:

```
### Automatically restore the volume of streams and devices
#load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore
```

Save the file and restart the service for effect:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

or if necessary  restart computer.